# MsBuild Database project Publish Profile

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, msbuild

We are using TFS and msbuild to deploy our web application using publish profiles. This is working perfectly, but I am trying to do the same for our database project, and I just can't get by the following error:
Error Deploy72002: Unable to connect to master or target server 'xxx'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'xxx'.

The value xxx is actually the name of the database, not the name of the server. I can't find a place to input the server name, and the server is actually xxx\yyy.
Anybody know how/where you would specify the server name or figure out what is wrong?

I am building the project, and using the following msbuild Arguments:
/t:build /t:Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath=PublishProfiles/QA.xxx.publish.xml /p:Configuration=Output

Answer (score 1):

> Anybody know how/where you would specify the server name or figure out what is wrong?

Do you have Windows authentication or SQL authentication?

For Windows authentication, you must **log on with an account that has certain permissions on that database**. The specific permissions that you need vary based on what action you want to perform. [This document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833413(v=vs.100).aspx) describe each action that you might want to perform and the specific permission that you need to perform it.

For SQL authentication, you need to modify publish profile file (.xml, TargetConnectString), for example:

```
<TargetConnectionString>Data Source=XXX;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True</TargetConnectionString>
```

Besides, you can build the project by using the following msbuild:

```
MSBUILD "....\TestProject.sqlproj" /t:build "/p:Platform=AnyCPU" /t:deploy /p:TargetConnectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=True" /p:TargetDatabase="xxx" /p:Configuration=Release /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0
```

Comment: I tried adding the password to the connection string, but that didn't help. It looks like what is actually happening is that the sql script is never created.

Comment: From what I understand, the Publish build script should be getting deployed to the output folder, but there is no sql file. What would prevent the creation of the sql script? Also, I am using SQL auth.

Comment: C:\TCIBuild02\_work\11\s\AppealTrack\Trunk\Database\AppealTrack.Database\AppealTrack.Database\bin\Release\AppealTrack.Database.publish.sql(0,0): Error Deploy72002: Unable to connect to master or target server 'AppealTrack'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'AppealTrack'.

Comment: AppealTrack is the database not the server. The SQL file is still not being generated, but I added it manually and still got the same error.

Comment: "but there is no sql file", that seems you could not publish successfully, Could you publish your database project successfully from Visual Studio and MSBuild command line on local machine?